How to remove unwanted space before math when using polyglossia in Russian?
I'm using polyglossia to create a document in Russian. If a sectioning command such as \section or \paragraph is immediately followed by an equation or other display-math, then there is unwanted extra space between them.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    \section{Architectural and structural solutions}
        \begin{equation}
            \sigma = E\varepsilon
        \end{equation}
\end{document}


If you write any line before the equation or if you use English, then the space becomes acceptable. Why is there extra space in this case? Is there a way to remove it for the entire document other than using negative \vspace in every case? Decreasing abovedisplayskip doesn't seem to change anything.

This is a common problem in LaTeX when indentfirst is in force, which it is with Russian and Polyglossia.
In the (unlikely) event that a display immediately follows a section title, precede it by \noindent.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\begin{document}

\section{Архитектурные и конструктивные решения}
Архитектурные и конструктивные решения
Архитектурные и конструктивные решения
Архитектурные и конструктивные решения
Архитектурные и конструктивные решения

\section{Архитектурные и конструктивные решения}
\noindent
\begin{equation}
  \sigma = E\varepsilon
\end{equation}

\selectlanguage{english}

\section{Architectural and structural solutions}

\begin{equation}
  \sigma = E\varepsilon
\end{equation}

\end{document}

(Translation courtesy of DeepL)

